# Return ReactiveMongo JSON in Play Framework

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

What is the fastest way to return JSON text from BSONArray?

I'm returning very big JSON document. Is it possible to omit processing `Play` `JsValue`

Now I'm returning like this:

```
 val result:BSONArray = ....
 Ok(Json.toJson(result))
```

I think faster would be something like:

```
 Ok(result.toTextJSON).as(MimeTypes.JSON)
```

Update here my full code:

```
val command = Json.parse( s""" {
  "aggregate": "$collection",
  "pipeline": [
  { "$$match": { "$$and" : [
      { "${RootAttrs.TIME}" : { "$$gt": $startSecTime }},
      { "${RootAttrs.TIME}" : { "$$lt": $endSecTime }},
      { "${RootAttrs.COMMAND}" : { "$$eq": ${toCmd(Command.GPS_COORDINATES)} }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$$sort": { "${RootAttrs.TIME}" : 1 }},
  { "$$limit": $MAX_GPS_ALL_DATA },
  { "$$project" : { "_id":0, "${RootAttrs.TIME}":1, "${RootAttrs.COMMAND}":1, "${RootAttrs.VALUE}":1, "${RootAttrs.IGNITION}":1, "${RootAttrs.SIM_NUMBER}":1 } }
]}""")

db.command(RawCommand(BSONDocumentFormat.reads(command).get)).map { out =>
  out.get("result").map {
    case result: BSONArray =>
      Logger.debug("Loaded all GPS history data size: " + result.length)
      Ok(Json.toJson(result)) // <- I need just return JSON, parsing to JsValue can take some time

    case _ =>
      Logger.error("Result GPS history data not array")
      BadRequest

  }.getOrElse(BadRequest)
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a more comprehensive code example here?

Answer (score -1):

You can bypass the step of creating the intermediary JsValue if you want to create your own Writeable, and output the string more manually.

Here is a simple example which can be customised to your need

```
val result: BSONArray = BSONArray("one", "two", "three")

def convertBsonArrayToString(jsval: BSONArray): Array[Byte] = {
  // this method assumes I have a BSONArray of Strings (which you may not)
  var strs: Stream[String] = jsval.stream.map(_.get match { case s: BSONString => s.value })
  var json: String = strs.mkString("[\"", "\",\"", "\"]")
  json.getBytes()
}

implicit def writeableOf_BSONArray: Writeable[BSONArray] = {
  Writeable(convertBsonArrayToString ,Some("application/json"))
}

def doStuff = action {
  Results.Ok(result)
}
```

The response above is ["one","two","three"]

If you are dealing with massive data - you may also be better off using an Enumerator, and streaming the response.

see: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream

Comment: It looks to me like reinventing the wheel.